# How to update next row in data grid using VB 6

Tags: vb6

Please help me how to update the next record in data grid using Visual Basic 6 as I am trying to add rec.movenext but only the first row updated. My code:

```
rec.Close
rec.Open "SELECT * FROM Salary WHERE UserID like '%" & Combo1.Text & "%'"

If rec.EOF Then
    rec.AddNew
Else
    rec.Update
    rec!Number = Text1.Text
    rec.MoveNext
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to do but it looks like the statements in the Else are reversed. If you want to update the next record, you should call MoveNext, set the value, then call Update. Note that if you query only returns one record then calling MoveNext will result in a EOF.

Comment: I am searching for ID number and then found three records and want to update each row separately by defining different value but i cannot do for the remaining records because the code is only updating first one , could you please help me and provide with a code that solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to update each of the records in a loop. Something like this

```
While Not rec.EOF
    rec!Number = Text1.Text
    rec.Update
    rec.MoveNext
Wend
```

Comment: Thanks Marc but the code updating all rows with same value ! Maybe there is something wrong with select statement , can you look on it and help me to fix the issue

Comment: It's setting the value to Text1.Text. That's all you have in your example. There's no way for me to know what you want to set the Number field to for each record. You will need to change rec!Number = Text1.Text to whatever you want to set it to in each iteration of the loop.

Comment: If you are needing to only update specific records, then place whatever if statements you'd need inside the while loop.  e.g., "if rec!fieldname = 'xyz' then..." and then just don't update the ones you want to leave as they are.